# React Native Promise, setState, and Navigation Issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm new to stack overflow so I hope I'm posting things correctly. I'm using React, React Native, and React Navigation. Basically, I need help in navigating from one screen to the next and passing along the data taken from a fetch request. It seems that the code works but the setState doesn't happen before navigation. If I go to the previous screen and navigate forward again, the response is there.

The help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
const [allResources, setAllResources] = React.useState([])
 
function getallresources() {
    fetch('API url', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        info: info1,
        info2: info2,
      }),
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => setAllResources(responseJson.allResources)
    .then(()=> navigation.navigate("AllResources", {allResources: allResources})
    )
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is not synchronous, though I'm not sure that's really the problem.  I would try passing the `responseJson.allResources` directly and seeing if that works to debug whether or not the state update is the issue:

```js
const [allResources, setAllResources] = React.useState([])
 
function getallresources() {
    fetch('API url', {...} ),
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
       setAllResources(responseJson.allResources)
       navigation.navigate("AllResources", {allResources: responseJson.allResources})
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
```

If that works, maybe `setState` really is the problem.  If so, you can navigate from a `useEffect` like this:

```js
useEffect( () => {
  if (allResources){
    navigation.navigate("AllResources", {allResources: allResources})
  }
}, [allResources])
```

(Of course take the `navigation.navigate` out of the `.then` callback.) If that doesn't work, you've got to look at how you're acessing your `allResources` our of your `params` in the AllResources screen.